# keybd_event function hold key issue

Tags: c#, keyboard-events

I am currently building a c# application which uses keybd_event to send key strokes to some other application. However it is not working as I expect it to be.

My press and release methods are like this:

```
public void PressKey(string key)
{
    var keyCode = Keycodes.StringToInt(key);
    keybd_event((byte)keyCode, 0, 0x0001 | 0, 0);
}

public void ReleaseKey(string key)
{
    var keyCode = Keycodes.StringToInt(key);
    keybd_event((byte)keyCode, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002, 0);
}
```

They are working properly as far as typing a letter to the other application. However when I try to hold a key, wierd behaviour occurs.

For example if I write:

```
PressKey("LeftShift");
```

I get the expected result. As the application runs, shift is pressed all the time.

However when I try this:

```
PressKey("W");
```

I expect to see infinite amount of "w"s typed. But instead I only get a single "w".

So my question here is that, why keybd_event does not treat all buttons the same? Or I am missing something in my methods?

Comment: Does the application you are sending the keystroke to accept repeating characters? I mean, if you hold the "w" key while the application is active, does the key repeat?

Comment: The repetition you see when holding down a key is produced by the keyboard controller.  A small micro-processor built into the keyboard.  You don't have one anymore when you poke keys in software, it is now up to you to do it.  Simply done with a Timer.

Comment: Yes, but how come the "Shift" is working but not "W"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular project I ended up using a 3rd party library [InputManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate) and it worked as expected.